# Problema con Make, Error: Se sale del directorio

Tags: c++, netbeans, make

Tengo una duda, hace unos días me funcionaba correctamaente mis proyectos de C++ de netbeans, pero hace unos momentos, me sale lo siguiente en la primera ventana de la consola condicionales(build, run):

cd '/home/beto/Documentos/C++/condicionales'

/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug

"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOeVS.png): se entra en el directorio '/home/beto/Documentos/C++/condicionales'

"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/condicionales

make[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdqET.png): se entra en el directorio '/home/beto/Documentos/C++/condicionales'

make[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdqET.png): 'dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/condicionales' está actualizado.

make[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdqET.png): se sale del directorio '/home/beto/Documentos/C++/condicionales'

make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOeVS.png): se sale del directorio '/home/beto/Documentos/C++/condicionales'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 684ms)

Y después me abre otra ventana de la consola (condicionales Run) con lo siguiente:

Ingrese un número entre [1-12]: 32764 no esta comprendido entre el rango [1-12]
RUN FINISHED; exit value 0; real time: 1s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms

Cabe recalcar que no me dejo meter ningun número, es asi con los demas programas que tengo, me sale lo de make: se sale del directorio, y después no me deja ingresar nada en los otros programas (si se dan cuenta me pone un número que yo no ingrese en la segunda ventana de la consola, pasa asi con los demas programas que tengo).

Les anexo también el código sencillo que estoy utilizando, no tengo idea de que haya sucedido:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int numero;
    cout<<"Ingrese un número entre [1-12]: ";cin>>numero;

    switch(numero){
        case 1: cout<<numero<<" corresponde al mes de enero"; break;
        case 2: cout<<numero<<" corresponde al mes de febrero"; break;
        case 3: cout<<numero<<" corresponde al mes de marzo"; break;
        case 4: cout<<numero<<" corresponde al mes de abril"; break;
        case 5: cout<<numero<<" corresponde al mes de mayo"; break;
        case 6: cout<<numero<<" corresponde al mes de junio"; break;
        case 7: cout<<numero<<" corresponde al mes de julio"; break;
        case 8: cout<<numero<<" corresponde al mes de agosto"; break;
        case 9: cout<<numero<<" corresponde al mes de septiembre"; break;
        case 10:    cout<<numero<<" corresponde al mes de octubre"; break;
        case 11:    cout<<numero<<" corresponde al mes de noviembre"; break;
        case 12:    cout<<numero<<" corresponde al mes de diciembre"; break;   
        default: cout<<numero<<" no esta comprendido entre el rango [1-12]"; break;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

---

No se si tenga que ver, que esta misma tarde se probo un código en el cual se usaba una variable demasiada grande y me hacia esto al ponerlo dentro del main (el código ya no lo tengo, pero era tambien sencillo, solo declaraba con `#define N 10000` y lo mostraba en el main).

Me pasa ahora con todos los proyectos que tengo de C++

En conclusión, me sale make: se sale del directorio, y no puedo ejecutar correctamente el programa, se abre y se termina de "ejecutar".

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Les dejo las imagenes de lo que me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso que dices que es el error, no es el error en si, es las notificaciones de make, debe haber un reporte de error, el cual empieza por `Error: mensaje de error`, por favor búscalo y actualiza tu pregunta con el.

Comment: Ya volví a editarlo, espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: Eres nuevo en la comunidad así que te invito a mirar [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) y [Qué evitar preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), ademas cuando edites una pregunta, hazlo en editar, que se encuentra justo debajo de la pregunta, también revisa bien tu supuesto error antes preguntar, porque en tu pregunta, tu error no es ni siquiera el que indicas. Tu código no posee ningún error, de hecho hace específicamente para lo que se programo, revisalo bien.

Comment: Ya se que no tiene ningun error, pero por eso publico aqui el problema que tengo, jamas me salio eso de salirse del directorio, ademas de que mi programa no se compila o ejecuta de forma correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Ya pude arreglarlo, después de mucho tiempo, lo que tuve que hacer era darle click derecho sobre los proyectos, irme a propiedades, y en la parte de run, donde dice Console Type elegir Standard Output, aplicar y aceptar y con es pude seguir ejecutando mis programas.

No se a que se debió que se cambiara esa opción y me diera dolor de cabeza, aceptaría alguna "respuesta" a lo que se debió, pero al tema principal lo he resuelto